# "В кухню" или "на кухню"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Когда мы говорим о других частях дома, то употребляем предлог "в": "пойти в комнату", "в коридор", "в ванную". Но только, когда речь заходит о кухне, употребляется предлог "на": "пойти на кухню". Почему так? Или все-таки это неправильно и нужно говорить "в кухню"?

Comment: Существует более поздний ответ, но более полный: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/16713/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5