# На кухне или в кухне?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно говорить?  "Я готовлю в кухне" - звучит как-то коряво. Но "в кухне светло".

Answer (score 3):

Предлоги В и НА могут быть синонимичными. Употребление предлога В в пространственном значении связано с представлением об ограниченном пространстве, при отсутствии этого значения употребляется предлог НА. Однако в некоторых случаях закрепляется один из синонимических предлогов: работать **в** фотостудии – работать **на** киностудии (на радио, на телевидении). Иногда сказывается исторически сложившаяся традиция; ср.: **в** деревне – **на** хуторе, **в** переулке – **на** улице. Думается, что с кухней та же ситуация: мы говорим "*на кухню*", "*на кухне*" в силу исторической традиции.

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас правильным считается вариант "на кухне". 
Если имеется в виду *место*, где готовят. Это может быть даже на открытом воздухе. 
Но если подразумевается именно комната, помещение и действие непосредственно с готовкой не связанное, то вполне возможно и "в кухне"
"В кухне светло" объясняется именно этим.

Answer (score 3):

Предлоги **В** и **НА** не всегда чётко разграничиваются:  обедать *в кухне* — обедать *на кухне*(вариант на кухне утвердился под влиянием народной речи). Сравните в литературе: Я побежал *в кухню* рассказать бабушке всё, что видел и слышал(М. Горький); Нянька приходила *на кухню* ужинать(В. Короленко).Исп. Розенталь Д. "Говорите и пишите по-русски правильно". "Грамота.ру" употребление предлогов В и НА (кухне) объясняет, что *оба варианта верны*.